Restful API-JSON mapping Issue after Migration from WebLogic 12c to WebLogic 14c
I currently maintain a legacy EJB application that is hosted on WebLogic 12c, where it operates smoothly without any issues. Recently, I undertook the task of migrating this application to WebLogic 14c, and while the migration was successful and the application began functioning properly, I observed a peculiar anomaly. Within the application, there exist several REST APIs whose request bodies comprise JSON objects with UpperCamelCase naming conventions. For instance, the JSON structure may appear as follows: { "UserId" : "XXX", "Name" : "XXX" ,…}. However, the corresponding objects intended for binding within the application utilize LowerCamelCase naming conventions. To ensure proper data mapping, each field in these objects is annotated with @XmlElement, as illustrated below:
public class User {
    @XmlElement(name = "UserId")
    String userId;
    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    String name;
    …
}

It is peculiar that upon calling the REST API with a request body structured as described on Weblogic 14c, I receive null values for every field utilizing the UpperCamelCase strategy. Conversely, when I employ lowerCamelCase in the request body, the API functions correctly. I am hesitant to modify the API requests, as they have been functioning seamlessly thus far. How can I address this issue on WebLogic 14c? What changes in WebLogic 14c have led to this problem post-migration from WebLogic 12c? Additionally, which dependencies, such as Jaxb or Jersey, should I consider reconfiguring on the server library?
In my legacy application, I currently rely on the following dependencies: Com.sun.jersey:Jersey-bundle-1.19.4, Javax:javaee-api-6.0, Com.fasterxml.jackson.core:Jackson-annotation:2.9

Did you move from JDK8 to JDK11 ?

The issue extends beyond just the JDK version. It is a large legacy application that partially utilizes SOA architecture and features tightly coupled dependencies. Due to its numerous subsystems, any changes to the JDK could disrupt its operation, especially after the challenges faced in migrating from JDK 7 to JDK 8. Migrating to WebLogic 14 is meant to address certain security vulnerabilities in recent updates. I believe the best approach is to resolve the identified problems separately from infrastructure changes like switching JDK versions.
